# Trouble getting accents to show up in my java app

Tags: java, localization, character-encoding, translation

We recently got a localization file the contains Portuguese translations of all the string in our java app.  The file they gave me was a .csv file and I use file maker to create .tab file which is what we need for our purposes.  Unfortunately none of the accents seem to work.  For example the string vocÍ in our localization file shows up as vocΩ inside the application.  I tried switching the language settings to portuguese before creating compiling but I still get this problem, anyone have any ideas of what else I might need to try?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you problem is related to the file encoding used.

Java has full unicode support so there shouldn't be any problems, unless the file you are reading (the one made with FileMaker) is encoded in something different than UTF8 (which is the default used by Java).

You can try saving the file in a different encoding or specifying which encoding to use when opening it from Java (see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html)). Many API classes support additional parameters to specify which charset to use when opening a file. Just take a look at the documentation..